# the 8 queens conjecture: the next level (or dimension)

Tags: geometry, chessboard

i know you have possibly seen [my last problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232287/the-8-queens-on-the-chessboard-variations/2232577#2232577) on the 8 Queens conjecture, and it was answered by a person named Peter Kagey. he mentioned that:

> With regard to a $n×n×n$ chessboard, one could simply place $n$ queens at the "bottom board" of the cube, and use the $n*n$ configuration. This argument shows that A000170 would serve as a lower bound on the number of configurations on the $n×n×⋯×n$ analog of the nonattacking queens problem.

If the sequence A000170 is the lower bound, what is the maximum number of queens that can go onto a 3-D chessboard? 4-D? so on?

> **EDIT** I am now just needing the $3\times 3\times 3$, $4\times 4\times 4$, and $5\times 5\times 5$ chess "cubes" i hope it isn't such a complex algorithm or massive time crunch.

Comment: It might be worth noting here (just to obviate the need to see your previous question) that by 'queen' you mean a piece that can travel in any straight line, not just orthogonally and diagonally.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki correct. i initially wanted a large sample(maybe a sequence in the OEIS) but i never got one. i then edited my question for this, making it less of a brainache.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what A000170 is, BTW. The maximum number of queens that can go onto an $n\times n$ chessboard for $n\gt 3$ is always $n$. That sequence just counts how _many_ ways that $n$ queens can go onto an $n\times n$ board.

Comment: It's easy to show that we can always get at least $n^2/13$ queens into an $n\times n\times n$ cube, incidentally (any one queen can only attack $13n$ cells - why? - so since there are $n^3$ cells available, we get the listed number by just arbitrarily picking an empty cell after each placement) and just as easy to show that we can have at most $n^2$ exactly (use the same reasoning that says that $n$ is a maximum for the 2d case). So the only real question is the exact growth between those bounds.